# Add one day to calendar to make test if-else

Tags: android, date, calendar

I use DateTime values in my app. I can create Lessons, and I have to set the beginning nd the end of that lesson.

Let's say I create like this :

```
English - Beginning 07.05.2017 End 07.07.2017
```

Then I want to modify the end of that lesson and put :

```
07.06.2017
```

I check to see if the dates are OK, but I'm not sure about what I did, because I dont want to let the user to modifiy or create lessons in the past, but if he creates a lesson that finishes the current day, that's ok.

I wrote like this in my if else :

```
       String date1 = datedebut.getText().toString();
        String date2 = datefin.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date_debutnew = dateFormat.parse(date_initial);
        Date date_derniernew = dateFormat.parse(date_derniercours);
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

     if (date_debutnew.after(date_derniernew) || date_derniernew.before(calendar.getTime())) 

    { ... }
```

How can I add one day to that calendar ?

Thank you for the future hlep.

Comment: What is `date_debutnew` and  `date_derniernew`? is it calender object?

Comment: Oh sry, date_debutnew is the new date of beginning after I modify the date of the lesson, and date_derniernew is the new date of end, they are Date objets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [compareTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method of Date.

> It will return,
>
> a value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date;
>
> a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument;
>
> a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

Comment: how can i convert that calendar to a Date?

Comment: `calendar.getTime()` method return date object.

Comment: It will return integer value not boolean value. So try with like this `if(date_derniernew.compareTo(calendar.getTime()) <=0) ` It means `date_derniernew` is before or equal to `calender` date.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the problem, your new Finish date should be after the new Start date and before the designated end Date.
so, the condition should be :

```
if (date_derniernew.after(date_debutnew) || date_derniernew.before(date2)) {
..}
```